# What do you put in the tiny box labeled 'inspiration' on a 5e D&D character sheet?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-sheets, inspiration

I'm creating a D&D character on the [character sheet generator by Levi Blodgett](https://levi-blodgett.github.io/dnd-char-generator/). I'm not sure what to put in the 'inspiration' box. I don't understand how your inspiration for your quest could fit in such a small box. Any ideas?

[image: Picture of the worksheet with the box circled]

Comment: Related: [What is inspiration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41852/23547)

Answer (score 23):

### To mark having inspiration.

The [rules for inspiration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#Inspiration) state:

> Inspiration is a rule the game master can use to reward you for playing your character in a way that’s true to his or her personality traits, ideal, bond, and flaw. By using inspiration, you can draw on your personality trait of compassion for the downtrodden to give you an edge in negotiating with the Beggar Prince. Or inspiration can let you call on your bond to the defense of your home village to push past the effect of a spell that has been laid on you.
>
> […]
>
> If you have inspiration, you can expend it when you make an attack roll, saving throw, or ability check. Spending your inspiration gives you advantage on that roll.

The basic rules contain additional rules (found at the link above) for gaining and using inspiration. That box on the character sheet is for marking when you have inspiration available.

Comment: You could also put a die of the appropriate size in that spot on your physical character sheet when you have Bardic inspiration. (d6 through d12 are possible depending on the bard's level, and a d20 for standard DM-granted inspiration.)

Answer (score 17):

### What's in the box!?

First off: you put nothing in the box. I've played and run hundreds of games using this sort of character sheet and can't remember ever seeing anyone put anything in that box.

Your gut instinct was perfectly reasonable: nobody's personal inspiration(s) for life could fit in that box. But "having inspiration" is a defined game term in D&D5e: it means you can roll an upcoming attack, ability check, or saving throw with *advantage* at your discretion. (See "Inspiration" at chapter 4: Personality and Backgrounds, PHB p.125.)

I guess, theoretically, you'd put a checkmark or an X or something in the box when you have inspiration, and erase it when you "spend" it. But I've never seen anyone do that. Personally, I have a few "sparkly" d20s that I hand to players when they earn inspiration, and they put those back in the center of the table after use.

("Advantage" is defined in chapter 7: it allows you to roll 2d20 and take the higher, basically.)

Comment: When you play online (for example on Roll20), instead of at the table, you can click the box to get a checkmark in it that looks like a little coiled up Dragon, and click it again when you use it up to remove it. We use it all the time. You can also use pencil to makr and erease it when playing at the table. I also heard of people putting little hearts into it, when they play on paper.

Comment: *have a few "sparkly" d20s* - what a great idea!!

Comment: I spray-painted some big metal discs gold to act as Inspiration tokens. Having something tangible to remind me to hand it out as the DM, and remind my players to use it, seemed like a good idea. Shiny d20s sounds even better! Everyone at my table still forgot to use them anyways.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin I guess it makes more sense in digital tools. Drawing and erasing an "x" (even more so a dragon xD) over and over again would be very inconvenient IRL

Comment: @PixelMaster - Yes, over time there is a lot of tough love that accumulates on those character sheets. One way I have personally used to get around it is to put the sheet in a transparent plastic sleeve, and use ereasable board marker you can easily and completely wipe off again on it.

Answer (score 9):

### Anything binary

[Inspiration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#GainingInspiration) exists in a binary state for each character:

> You either have inspiration or you don’t - you can’t stockpile multiple “inspirations” for later use.

Since it can be in only two states, the box has one mark if you have it and a different mark (or nothing) if you don't.  As the [Hobgoblin says](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/209869/what-do-you-put-in-the-tiny-box-labeled-inspiration-on-a-5e-dd-character-shee#comment576923_209871), on roll20 when you click on the box you can toggle between a coiled dragon symbol and an empty box - but not write anything in there.

Comment: I don't usually ask for downvoters to explain themselves, but I was surprised by the overnight vehemence with which this was downvoted.  At the time of writing, no other answer had cited the have/not have quote about inspiration and no other _answer_ had mentioned how the space is used in VTTs.  I thought both were useful additions to the already good answers.  This certainly isn't _better_ then what was already here - but I would like to know why it is considered _bad_.

Comment: me too (surprised, that is), to the extent I almost left a similar comment. But I couldn't get the phrasing right in the end.... Glad to see the tide's turned =)

Comment: @nitsua60 Thanks.  Yes, it's swung around now, which is gratifying - but still perplexing for the original experience.  I wrote the answer, went to bed, and in the morning it was at -6.  I was just scratching my head, what in the answer is _so_ wrong or unuseful?